# VSCode extension for displaying key input

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a extension for displaying key input in vscode?

I am moving on to VSCode from Atom. Since atom provided key detect feature natively, I could easily find key conflicts.

Does VSCode have the same feature in it?

Answer (score 2):

In vscode v1.49 a new method for troubleshooting keybindings is being added:

> #### Troubleshooting keybindings
>
> To troubleshoot keybindings problems, you can now execute the command
> `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`. This will
> activate logging of dispatching keyboard shortcuts and will open an
> output panel with the corresponding log file.
>
> Then, if you press your desired keybinding, you can check what VS Code
> detects and what command is invoked.
>
> e.g. Pressing `cmd+/` in a code editor, on a macbook:
>
> [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers:
> [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta

> [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode:
> 57 ('Meta')

> [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched.

> [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event -
> modifiers: [meta], code: Slash, keyCode: 191, key: /
> [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [meta],
> code: Slash, keyCode: 85 ('/')

> [KeybindingService]: | Resolving meta+[Slash]

> [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched
> editor.action.commentLine, when: editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly,
> source: built-in.

> The first keydown event is for the `MetaLeft` key (`cmd`) and cannot
> be dispatched.

> The second keydown event is for the `Slash` key (`/`)
> and is dispatched as `meta+[Slash]`. There were two keybinding entries
> mapped from `meta+[Slash]` and the one that matched was for the
> command `editor.action.commentLine`, had the `when` condition
> `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly` and was a built in keybinding
> entry.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#troubleshooting-keybindings

---

You can find key conflicts on a per command basis. See [detecting key binding conflicts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_detecting-keybinding-conflicts).

> The Keyboard Shortcuts editor has a context menu command Show
> Conflicts, which will filter the keybindings based on a keyboard
> shortcut to display conflicts.

[image: from vscode docs: key binding conflicts]

> Pick a command with the keybinding you think is overloaded and you can
> see if multiple commands are defined, the source of the keybindings
> and when they are active.

[image: from vscode docs: key binding conflicts]

There is also a command that can show the conflicts as well:

```
"command": "keybindings.editor.showConflicts"
```

which could be bound to a keybinding instead of invoking the context menu and selecting "Show Conflicts".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to see what command is called in a dynamic view. In Atom's input detection, you can see what command the key input calls for every step of your inputs. With this feature, I can see what command is called among the candidate commands.

Comment: Not sure I understand... Do you mean if your candidate keybinding is Ctrl-C Ctrl-K you want to first see conflicts for Ctrl-C and then filter those down to include the Ctrl-K's?  If so, you can just type "CTRL-C" and it will show only those and then add "Ctrl-K" to the end of that to see if there are any more already bound commands.  [In the Keyboard Shortcuts search box.]

Comment: I mean I want to see which command is called if there are multiple commands mapped to a single keybinding. If command+c is mapped to "copy" and "clear", in some case, "copy" will be called according to the environment, such as Vim extension mode, and in some case, "clear" will be. Atom provides "keybinding resolver" for this purpose.